# React inline conditional return Unexpected token, expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like add inline conditional in my React Component, but i don't understand why, React return **Unexpected token, expected** on the line `posts.length ?` :

```
class PostList extends Component {

  getPosts() {
    const posts = Post.find().fetch();
    return posts;
  }

  render() {
    const posts = this.getPosts();
    return (
      {posts.length ?
        <ul>
          {posts.map((post) => (
            <PostItem key={post.title} post={post} />
          ))}
        </ul>
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Anyone have idea ? My conditional is wrong ?

Thank you community !

Comment: Yes, your conditional is wrong: a ternary expression must have both the `?` part and the `:` part, and you cannot drop an expression into a `{ }` object initializer like that anyway.

Comment: have you tried using an extra ? .   `{ posts.length ??`

Comment: @Ollie: That's not valid syntax, is it? I've never seen `??` in JavaScript before, only in C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return `null` when expression evaluates as `false`.Also Dont use the `{}`, use this `()`

```js
class PostList extends React.Component {
    
      getPosts() {
        //const posts = Post.find().fetch();
       const posts = ["post1","post2"]
        return posts;
      }
    
      render() {
        const posts = this.getPosts();
        return (
            posts.length ?
              <ul>
                {posts.map((post) => (
                  <PostItem key={post.title} post={post} />
                ))}
              </ul>:
              null
        )
      }
    
    }
    
    class PostItem extends React.Component{
    render(){
      return (<div>{this.props.post}</div>)
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<PostList />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: @Chris Yeah, i got the error. I'll update my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slight syntactic variation to [anuragasaurus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5182917/anuragasaurus) answer.

If there is no "else" in your condition you don't need a ternary expression `condition ? value1 : value2`. You can instead use a [**Short-circuit evaluation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation):

> As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, they are tested
>   for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules:
>
> - `false && (anything)` is short-circuit evaluated to false.
> - `true || (anything)` is short-circuit evaluated to true.
>
> The rules of logic
>   guarantee that these evaluations are always correct. Note that the
>   anything part of the above expressions is not evaluated, so any side
>   effects of doing so do not take effect. Also note that the anything
>   part of the above expression is any single logical expression (as
>   indicated by the parentheses).

---

```
class PostList extends Component {

  getPosts() {
    const posts = Post.find().fetch();
    return posts;
  }

  render() {
    const posts = this.getPosts();
    return (
      posts.length &&
        <ul>
          {posts.map((post) => <PostItem key={post.title} post={post} />)}
        </ul>
    );
  }    
}
```

Comment: It still gives the error .You will need to wrap the code in a `div` block. So that the component doesn't returns `null` in some cases.

Comment: @anuragasaurus, I don't think so. A component can return null or false.

Comment: @Chris remove `{}` around `{posts.length &&
       ....
      }` it should be `return(posts.length &&
       ....
      )`